# VB.NET Single object instance only

Tags: vb.net, oop, object, instance

VB.NET: What is the best way to ensure that a particular object may be instantiated only once during program execution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at these

- [Introduction to the Singleton
  Pattern in VB.NET](http://vbnotebookfor.net/2007/09/13/introduction-to-the-singleton-pattern-in-vbnet/)
- [VB.NET OOP Part 3: The Singleton
  Pattern](http://ondotnet.com/pub/a/dotnet/2002/11/11/singleton.html)
- [Creational Patterns - Singleton
  using VB.NET](http://www.vbdotnetheaven.com/UploadFile/susanabraham/CreationalPatternsvb11122005001524AM/CreationalPatternsvb.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You need a Singleton.

There a great article (unfortunately in C#) here: http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/singleton.html

But you'll be able to translate to VB quite easily.

You want the 2 last implementations.

further explanations here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern

Mike

Answer (score 0):

1. Use a module.
2. Use this code

_

```
Class MySpecialClass
    Private Sub New()
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly SingleInstance As New MySpecialClass
End Class
```

Edit: WTF? Why is the code formatting broken?

Comment: Adding in a dummy character as above seems to fix it; but it's not clear why one can't go straight from a numbered list into a code section.